# How to host Asp.Net website on VPS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, web-deployment

I have purchased a VPS of Arvixe to deploy my ASP.NET website there, I have deployed the website on IIS of that VPS and it is working perfectly fine on that machine.

But now i want to make that website public so that anyone can access it through IP address of that VPS. Can you please help me, how i can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Tell the public the IP address.

Comment: Tell YOUR USERS the public IP address. This address seems to be the one for the administration. Remove your comment for security reasons!

Comment: Have you tried Arvixe Support?

Comment: At what address is the site running when you're able to see it running perfectly fine?

Comment: So your public site is bound to port 82, which is likely blocked by the firewall. How come you've got your admin site on port 80 and your public one on 82? I think if they were the other way round your problem would be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was firewall of VPS, because it was blocking my ports.